# Conditional mapping if string null in Drool

Tags: drools, rule, rule-engine

I have a Rule Template that uses expression (drool) to map parameters to conditions/actions.

```
<mapping>Fact(action == '{Parameter}')</mapping>
```

Problem is when I have a rule where `{Parameter}` is null or empty string I receive in the REST client

```
<action>{Parameter}</action>
```

instead of

```
<action></action>
```

How can I conditionnaly map my parameter like :

```
<mapping>Fact(action == {Parameter} ? '{Parameter}' : null)</mapping>
```